# Android CountDownLatch.await() freezes UI prematurely

Tags: android, countdownlatch

So I am running some threads with a CountDownLatch.

My problem is that when I call latch.await() the UI seems to hang and even UI commands that were called beforehand have no effect. e.g.

```
btnShare.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
prgSharing.setVisibility(View.VISIBILE);

latch.await()
```

The first two lines have no effect on the UI.

Any idea why this is and possibly a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because you are blocking the `UI-Thread` before it can render the `Views` again. I think you should look at [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and maybe put your `wait` logic in the `doInBackground()` method, or somehow re-think your implementation.

Comment: Good idea, in my UI Thread I am processing the multiple web tasks but offload this to a AsyncTask where I can then await() for the two to finish and pass the final result back to the UI Thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if the UI hangs it is because you call:

```
latch.await()
```

on the `UI Thread.` You have to avoid blocking call on the UI Thread since those are the cause of `ANR`